# How to get indexof() counted from the end of string

Tags: javascript, indexof

If I have the string: "354-567-3425 | John Doe" how can I find how many characters are after the "|" symbol?  I googled and all that I found was the javascript `indexOf()` method.  That would work if I was trying to find the number of symbols BEFORE the "|", but I'm not sure how to run `indexOf()` counting backwards, if you know what I mean.  I'm sure there's an easy solution.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I like all of these answers. It shows you that in programming, no matter what you want to do, there is always more than one way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say like bellow

```
var str = '354-567-3425 | John Doe';
var indexFromLast = str.length - str.indexOf('|');
```

the `indexFromLast` has the index from end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lastIndexOf()` instead of `indexOf()`

Details on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

Comment: This answer does not help in the explained situation, because the index is still counted from left, not right.

Answer (score 1):

try this snippet of code, it should work.

```
var yourString = "354-567-3425 | John Doe";
var index = yourString.indexOf("|");
var lengthYouWant = yourString.slice(index + 1).length;
```

Comment: You really should terminate your statements with semicolons. It isn't strictly necessary, true, but it avoids an ugly class of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

If your value is always going to have a single `|` separator, then you can find the total number of characters after the `|` with the following:

`'354-567-3425 | John Doe'.split('|')[1].length`

Here's another way to do it if the number of `|` is not regular:

```
var data = '354-567-3425 | John Doe | 666 Elm Street';
var lastIndexPos = data.lastIndexOf('|');
console.log(data.substr(lastIndexPos + 1).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "354-567-3425 | John Doe";
var charsAfter = str.length - str.indexOf("|") - 1;
```

The `- 1` is to move past the `|` character.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like the following:

```
 var myString= '354-567-3425 | John Doe';
 myString.substr(myString.indexOf('|') + 1)
```